# Diode Circuit find voltage

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes

I have this circuit:

[image]

I know that D1 is cut-off and ID2=1.33mA. How can I find the V?

In the answer of this excercise it says that V=VΒ=-10+10*1.33=3.3V.
Is it correct? If yes, how did it come of and why is the V we are searching the same as the V in B?

Comment: I assume we are looking at ideal diodes here.

Comment: why is D1 in cutoff region?

Comment: @RoyC Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10*1.33 is the 10k resistor voltage drop(1.33 mA). From the -10V to the B point, the voltage difference is on that resistor. V = VB=-10+voltage drop. The diode being ideal V is the same as in B.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume no current flow out of the terminal then it becomes trivial:

Given I<sub>D2</sub> = 1.33mA then using ohms law voltage on the 5k resistor must be 5000*0.00133 = 6.65 V
If one end of the resistor is at +10V then the other end must be at 10-6.65 = 3.35 V

For non-ideal parts and a load current run a DC sweep simulation of this with a varying value for R3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6tuIj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>